# GreaseMonkey Hello World

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Any ideas why this script isn't working?

Also, when I install the script the Name and Description field are blank?

```
//==UserScript==
//@name testName
//@namespace anonDeveloper
//@description This script will automagically blah blah blah
//@include *
//==/UserScript==
alert('Hello world!');
```

The script is located on my file system rather than some URI. Could that be causing the issue?

Comment: Andy E's answer is correct.  The spaces missing from your code are required by GM -- as silly as that seems.

Answer (score 12):

It works for me in the latest Google Chrome (you didn't say which browsers you tested).  However, in order for the name and description to correctly display, you need to add a space after each `//`:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name testName
// @namespace anonDeveloper
// @description This script will automagically blah blah blah
// @include *
// ==/UserScript==
alert('Hello world!');
```

Comment: I'm using firefox on Ubuntu. I'm installing the script then going to google.com and I get no alert?

Comment: @joe  I can confirm this is working for me too.  Are you saving this and then opening a new browser page or reloading?

Comment: Works on my chrome. Why the plugin doesn't create this template by default I don't know.